# How to push new git on the same project on Heroku

Tags: php, git, heroku

Let's suppose that I am running a very elementary 'Hello World' PHP script on Heroku. So I have created a git repository at Github with a simple 'Hello World' php script and an empty README file plus an empty json file. The git has the name `sample`. Therefore the source code in the php script is:

```
<?php

echo 'Hello World';

?>
```

I applied step-by-step the instructions at Heroku:

- I downloaded the Heroku CLI
- entered `heroku login` and my credentials at the command line
- had php, composer and git installed
- entered `git clone *my_git_repository_adress*` (cloning a repository from Github)
- entered `cd *my_git_repository_name*`
- entered `heroku create`
- entered `git push heroku master`

The project is running properly and 'Hello World' is printed on the relevant url.

My question i the following: how can I DIRECTLY edit the content of my php script (and write more complex things than a simple 'Hello World') instead of creating a new repository on Github, iterating the same process above and creating a new project?

Therefore, I want to edit the php scipt of this project without having to iterate the same process and creating a new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really get your question, once you have done those steps you don't have to do them again.

cd *the folder where your php script is*
edit your php script 'Hello world 2' then:

```
git add .
git commit -m "my new commit"
git push origin master
git push heroku master
```

and your code should be live after the deployment.

If you are using GitHub, you should use directly your GitHub repository on heroku and avoid the last step.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So do you mean to edit my php script on my local machine (on Users/User/) and then enter what you wrote above at your post?

Comment: If you have a regular configuration of your environment the commands above should work.
git push origin master > pushes the code to GitHub,
git push heroku master > pushes code to heroku and triggers the deployment

Comment: Ok I get it. But my comment asks you something very specific.

Comment: Also where exactly should I enter what you wrote? After entering `cd *git_name*` in the command line?

Comment: Yes exactly you go in the folder you cloned before, so you cd *directory*, then edit the file and run the commands above

Comment: Also keep in mind that my php script, the README file and the json file are within a git/folder called `sample`.

Comment: Ok but let's be a bit more clear. 1) I go to /Users/User/Sample and I edit my php script, 2) I go to terminal and enter `cd sample`, 3) I enter the code that you wrote above.

Comment: (By the way, shall I replace `"my new commit"` with a specific name related to my file or I enter it like this?)

Comment: Yes do that, I edited my answers with a more generic answer

Comment: "my new commit " is just a comment, usually explains what you did in the commit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167170/discussion-between-jawbonewalk-and-poete-maudit).